# Как можно себя обезопасить от строк у которых нет конца '\0' при использование функции snprintf()

Tags: c

Бывает так что попадаются строки не имеющие символа конца и функция snprintf() вызывает критическую ошибку.
Как можно проверять, что строки корректные и можно вызывать функцию snprintf ?

Мой код:

```
    typedef struct {
    const char name[20];         // имя
    const char textExtension[4]; // расширение
    const uint32_t size;         // размер в байтах
    const uniondate date;        // дата
    const uiniontime time;       // время
    const uint32_t numberSector; // номер сектора
    const uint32_t crc;          // контрольная сумма
    const uint32_t reserve[5];   // резерв
} const headerFileList;
extern const headerFileList *HeaderFileList[256]; 

   char text[32];
   memset(text,0,sizeof(text));

'snprintf(text, sizeof(text),"%s%c%s", HeaderFileList[i]->name, '.', HeaderFileList[i]->textExtension);
```

если
'HeaderFileList[i]->name' и 'HeaderFileList[i]->textExtension' массив заполнен 'ff' то snprintf не работает.

Comment: Ваш `sizeof(text)` всегда возвращает 8. Так как размер указателя равен восьми байтам *(у  вас скорее-всего так)*. Сначала исправьте эту ошибку. Предоставьте правильный размер.

Comment: У меня 'uint8_t text[32];' sizeof возвращает 32.

Comment: Добавьте `uint8_t text[32];` в вопрос. И типы в структуре.

Comment: **Как можно проверять, что строки корректные и можно вызывать функцию snprintf ?* - а в общем случае никак. Программист должен сам предоставить такие гарантии. Поэтому си и не любят многие программисты, которые не готовы к такому.

Comment: А как вы вообще определяете такую строку? Где она заканчивается?

Comment: `snprintf` не виноват. он печатает максимум 32 байта. А поля `name` или `textExtension` если без конца строки `\00` уже вызывают исключение. Вы должны сами в этих полях последнюю букву настойчиво ставить нулю. `->name[19] = '\00'` `->textExtension[3]='\00'`

Comment: Я так и делаю. Думал может есть что-то более корректное.

Comment: очень часто, memset на всю структуру (для зануления) может сильно помочь

Comment: У меня структура типа 'const' я могу только читать писать туда не могу.

Comment: тогда у Вас два базовых варианта. Доверится апи или разобраться, что там да как. ну и всегда остается вариант поискать библиотеку/забить

Comment: Делать копирование строк с гарантированным заканчивающимся нулевым символом. И печатать будет уже безопасно.

Comment: Я так и сделал.

Comment: Если объекты структур имеют квалификатор `const`, то претензии надо предъявлять к тому, кто такую чушь (недозаполненные поля) предоставил.